# Node.js unit testing (in 2013)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I saw in StackOverflow that two years ago Expresso, Vows and Mocha were good options for unit testing in node.js, but what about now? I haven't found more recent questions.

Comment: Having to ask "*how about now*" is a large part of why these types of questions [are considered off-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). They're likely to draw mostly opinionated answers and can fall out-of-date easily.

Comment: If you're just looking for a list of possibilities, Node.js has a Wiki page of Modules: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#testing--spec-frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocha is the most popular unit testing framework but I don't like it very much because the error parameter should be an Error object, for example you can't pass an array of errors. Tap and should.js are also pretty good.

If you don't need all the features of these frameworks you can build your own with the built-in `assert` module. No dependencies, no bloated code, just a few lines, easy.

```
var tests = {
    "description 1": function (done){
        testSomethingAsync (function (error){
            assert.ifError (error);

            //assert other things

            done ();
        });
    },
    "description 2": function (){
        var res = testSomethingSync ();
        //assert other things
    }
};

var keys = Object.keys (tests);
var keysLength = keys.length;

(function again (i){
    if (i<keysLength){
        var fn = tests[keys[i]];
        if (fn.length){
            fn (function (){
                again (i + 1);
            });
        }else{
            fn ();
            again (i + 1);
        }
    }
})(0);
```

Comment: Having used mocha too I liked the behavior driven development approach using "should" instead of assert. In my opinion it is a better way for testing applications.

Comment: test-studio is an npm package that provides a powerful, web based front end for unit testing. It supports things like executing individual or groups of tests and stepping node-inspector into individual tests.

Read more about it at https://www.npmjs.org/package/test-studio and http://www.danderson00.com/2014/05/test-studio-unit-testing-for-nodejs-how.html.